# plotting 2 axis figure in R pdf version loses right hand axis label

Tags: r, pdf, plot

Screen plot works perfectly, but pdf version loses `'mtext' "incidence (%)"`

```
# data

hgf <- c(394,441,592,559,455,542,583,548,636,709)
incfor <- c(11.2,13.0,13.5,12.0,7.8,8.0,8.4,8.4,8.8,9.5)

par(mar=c(5,4,4,5)+.1)
index <- 1:10
period <- c("9801","9902","0003","0104","0205", "0306",
            "0407","0508","0609","0710")
```

The screen plot

```
bp <- barplot(hgf, ylim=c(0,800),cex.axis=1.0,yaxt="n")
axis(2, at=seq(0,800,200))
axis(1, at=bp,labels=period,cex.axis=1.0,las=2 )
par(new=TRUE)

plot(bp,incfor,type="l",col="blue",
  cex.axis=1.0,cex.lab=1.0,
  xaxt="n",yaxt="n",xlab="period",ylab="",ylim=c(0,16),lwd=2)
par(cex.axis=1.0)
axis(4, at=seq(0,16,2))
mtext("incidence % (line, rhs)",side=4,line=2,cex=1.0)
mtext("number (bar, lhs)",side=2,line=2,cex=1.0)
grid(nx=NULL,col="black")
```

The pdf version

```
par(mar=c(5,4,4,5)+.1)

pdf(file="fig_hgf_for.pdf",
  useDingbats=F)

bp <- barplot(hgf, ylim=c(0,800),cex.axis=1.0,yaxt="n")
axis(2, at=seq(0,800,200))
axis(1, at=bp,labels=period,cex.axis=1.0,las=2 )
par(new=TRUE)

plot(bp,incfor,type="l",col="blue",
  cex.axis=1.0,cex.lab=1.0,
  xaxt="n",yaxt="n",xlab="period",ylab="",ylim=c(0,16),lwd=2)
par(cex.axis=1.0)
axis(4, at=seq(0,16,2))
mtext("incidence % (line, rhs)",
  side=4,line=2,cex=1)
mtext("number (bar, lhs)",side=2,line=2,cex=1)
grid(nx=NULL,col="black")

dev.off()
```

Answer (score 2):

`pdf()` opens a new device with default `par` settings, nullifying your earlier `par(mar=...)` call.

Bottomline: run `par(mar=...)` after `pdf(...)` and it looks fine.

Comment: extraordinary! as you say, looks fine! ma-d